# LibGDX - change state of ImageButton without calling 'click' event

Tags: android, libgdx, imagebutton

In `LibGDX` I have `ImageButton` with event for clicking.

```
myBtn.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            checkIfOtherButtnsPressed()
        }
    });
```

I have some buttons and what I do in `checkIfOtherButtnsPressed()` is checking the state of other buttons, if a button was pressed and one other has also in active state I change it state to

```
selected = false;
```

the problem is after changing it state from active to not-active  it also call the event like I 'cliked' on it and I get into `checkIfOtherButtnsPressed()` again.

Can I chaneg the button state without dispaching the click event, or can I recognize from what situation was the 'click' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know proper method names for libgdx but simple logic is you should remove listener when you change state and set listener again after state changed.

```
myBtn.addListener(null);
myBtn.setSelected([true|false]);
myBtn.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            checkIfOtherButtnsPressed()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside this you can use an **Image** which is also a type of an actor and take a drawable and whenever another actor is clicked on that time you can change your **Image** *drawable*.

```
Image imgBtn=new Image(drawableNonFocus);
imgBtn.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeIfOtherButtonPressed();
        }
    });


    private void changeIfOtherButtonPressed()
    {
        imgBtn.setDrawable(drawableFocus);
    }
```

You can change the drawable as shown in the above method named **changeIfOtherButtonPressed()**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Using the Libgdx features on Android. Libgdx offers way to get around the physical button aspect of applications.
Firstly, you're going to want to make a sprite and load it into your `onCreate()` method of any class that @overrides your main class that extends the Libgdx `Game` class. This will load the sprite ready to be called into your `renderer()` method, you'll then need to assign a spritebatch to your renderer and call a draw method from that to an assigned co-ordinates.

```
SpriteBatch batcher;
Batcher.draw(x, y, width, height) Documentation for [drawing][1]
```

Then Assign a boundary rectangle to the button. Your listener will then be triggered when the user touches a certain point on the screen matching to your button position.

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    guiCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
            if (pauseBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
                SoundHandler.playSound(SoundHandler.clickSound);
                state = ConstantsHandler.GAME_PAUSED;
                return;
            }
        }
```

A snippet taken from the SuperJumper demo provided by Libgdx will give you a great starting point on dealing with Graphical based events. [link here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper) it's always better to use Libgdx methods that have implemented Android's current libraries due to Android having various methods that are not compatible with Libgdx classes which leads to uneccasary debugging or a crashed application in the future.

This isn't the solution to your current problem, but an alternative route to help with future problems.